# Add loaded routes from REST in runtime in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-routing

This is a really strange behavior I just found using Angular-CLI. A ticket has been raised at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4234.

There seems to be a bug when adding routes dynamically using router.resetConfig() method. I'm not sure if it's a bug in Angular-CLI, Angular compiler, Angular Router or Webpack. I just want to share the issue so you don't end up your day banging your head into the wall.

**This is the setup:**

```
## routes.json
[
    { "path": "contact", "loadChildren": "./contact/contact.module#ContactModule" }
]

## RouterService.ts
getRotues() {
   return this._http.get('routes.json')
     .map((res) => res.json())
}
```

**Now to the actual bug:**

```
let routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ]
})

export class AppModule {
  constructor(private router:Router, private routerService:RouterService) {
    // This works
    // Pushing the same route as in routes.json
    // ----------------------
    routes.push({ path: 'contact', loadChildren: './contact/contact.module#ContactModule' })
    router.resetConfig(router);

    // This does not work
    // Loads json data from service and push the new route
    // ----------------------
    this.routerService.getRoutes().subscribe((result) => {
      result.forEach((route) => {
        routes.push({ path: route.path, loadChildren: route.loadChildren })
      });
      this.router.resetConfig(routes);
    });

    // This does works
    // By just console log this anonymous object, the loaded routing from the 
    // json data will work. 
    // ----------------------
    console.log({ loadChildren: './contact/contact.module#ContactModule' })
    this.routerService.getRoutes().subscribe((result) => {
      result.forEach((route) => {
        routes.push({ path: route.path, loadChildren: route.loadChildren })
      });
      this.router.resetConfig(routes);
    });
  }
```

This was tested on 
Windows 7, 
Angular-CLI (1.0.0-beta.21 & 1.0.0-beta.26)
Node 5.8.0

The question is, am I the first on the planet to add routes from a REST service or have someone made a workaround for this?

Comment: Same issue. Looking for a solution.

Comment: Any updates on this? Absolute pain in the neck trying to figure it out!